# Woocommerce - Remove 'Billing' word from the error message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When using Woocommerce 2.6.4 in the check-out error the required field names automatically gets 'Billing' as a prefix in the error-msg, even thought the label text is set.

```
Ex. "Billing First Name is required"
```

The error is produced from here:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error">
   <?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
        <li><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

In functions.php, the label name are set lik this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );

function custom_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Remove Label text
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'First Name';


    return $fields;
}
```

**How can I remove "Billing" as a prefix in the error message?**

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_first_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'First Name is required' ), 'error' );
}

Comment: Beautiful! That made me able to add another error-msg for the particular field. How do I hide the original error-msg?

Answer (score 16):

Use [`woocommerce_add_{$notice_type}`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_add_notice.html#88) filter.

E.g.

```
function customize_wc_errors( $error ) {
    if ( strpos( $error, 'Billing ' ) !== false ) {
        $error = str_replace("Billing ", "", $error);
    }
    return $error;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'customize_wc_errors' );
```

Comment: Any other place on affected? how to override woocommerce include file